# Infinite loop in set range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure why this keeps looping infinitely. Although I set my range, my code does not exit the loop after all the rows in my range (rng) have been examined.

```
Option Explicit

Sub prnt()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim row As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B8:F57")

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        For Each cell In rng.Rows.Cells
            If cell <> "" Then
                cell.Copy
                Range("i8").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial
                i = i + 1
            Else
            End If

        Next cell

    Next row


End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each cell In row.Cells` not `For Each cell In rng.Rows.Cells`

Comment: @TimWilliams: not disagreeing, just wondering: if he just wants to go through all cells in the list, why two loops, why not just `For Each cell In rng.Rows.Cells` ?

Comment: @Ditto you are correct only one loop is necessary, unless he wants to do something between the rows. But as the OP has it written what you said is true, except remove the `.rows` so only `For Each cell in rng.cells`

Comment: Not knowing your situation, you may be able to loop through each non-blank cell,`Set rng = Range("B8:F57").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)`

Comment: @ScottCraner: Thanks for clarifying, I wasn't sure if it was `rng.cells` or `rng.rows.cells` myself ;)

Comment: I highly recommend not using `row` and `cell` as a variable name, as these are VBA Specific words (well, `cell` is awfully close anyways).  Just as you didn't use `range`, but `rng`, I would recommend using `cel` and `xRow` (or something).  That is just to prevent any confusion by VBA or yourself when reviewing code.  For instance, I think you'll get an error if you wanted to use your `cell`'s row in that loop.  `cell.row` is *two* variables...Just a thought anyways!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I had to properly format your code to look at this problem, and here it is, properly indented without the whitespace and with the `cell` variable swapped for `cel`, and the `row` variable swapped for `rngRow`:

```
Sub prnt()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim cel As Range
   Dim rngRow As Range

   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B8:F57")

   For Each rngRow In rng.Rows
       For Each cel In rng.Rows.Cells
            If cel <> "" Then
                cel.Copy
                Range("i8").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial
                i = i + 1
            Else

            End If
        Next cell
    Next row
End Sub
```

Immediately I notice that your first loop does literally nothing for the code. You use `rngRow` (or `row` in your original) as the loop control variable, but never refer to it in the code itself, so already the program takes 50 times longer to process, because you are cycling through 250 cells, 50 times each for no reason at the moment.

The `rngRow` variable is being set to `B8:F8`, then `B9:F9` etc, for each loop.

The `cel` variable is being set to `B8`, `C8`, `D8` ... `B9`, `C9` etc before `rngRow` gets set to `B9:F9`, so as I said above, you'll end up with 50 duplicate values for any cell in that range that does not evaluate to "".

This code fixes that, and it checks the text attribute of the cell, so it won't break if it comes across a cell error (#N/A etc)

```
Sub prnt()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B8:F57")

    For Each cel In rng.Rows.Cells
        If cel.Text <> "" Then
            cel.Copy
            Range("i8").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Apologies if this sounded condescending, that was not my intention.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why not abandon the dreaded clipboard and assign directly: `Range("i8").Offset(i, 0).Text = cel.Text` ?

Comment: @user1016274 because sometimes you also want formatting, conditional formatting, validation, formulas, and even error states to be retained, and AFAIK the best way is to copy/paste.